# changed the entity mapping name from "/index" to "/indexemploye" and got this error

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, thymeleaf

I have saved both errors logs from the browser and IDE console into these 2 pdf files below:

[browser error log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1091E0utM7ckqHnuK68eUtlhnsttCbIFk/view?usp=sharing)

[IDE console error log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16moQ6J4u9V1cnjO8IGzqQcwIRHg25-K7/view?usp=sharing)

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/URq8M.jpg

---

codebase (source code link): https://github.com/ismailalabou/service-mvc.git

Comment: Share codes. which part is causing error.

Comment: @krishnkantjaiswal will do

Comment: @krishnkantjaiswal https://github.com/ismailalabou/service-mvc.git

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "currentPage==status.indexemploye" (template: "employes" - line 44, col 11)
```

Looks like a find and replace gone wrong.

Comment: hey @metroids, I don't think so. I can you recheck the image I just uploaded.

Comment: it said: "Property or field 'indexemploye' cannot be found on object of type 'org.thymeleaf.engine.IterationStatusVar' - maybe not public or not valid?"

Comment: Uhh... the code used  to say `status.index` and now it says `status.indexemploye`.  `status.indexemploye` is wrong, `status.index` is correct.  I'm assuming you did a find/replace on index and now it's incorrect.

Comment: why can't I change the name ?

Comment: Because in a th:each the second variable is created by thymeleaf, and has certain properties which can't be changed.  You didn't write the Thymeleaf iteration status variable, so how can you change it's properties?  See this: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status

Comment: I'm still confused with this. can u point me to the changes should I do in employes.html !

Comment: hey @metroids can we move this discussion to github. cause i'm getting some warnings here. thank you

Comment: https://github.com/ismailalabou/service-mvc/discussions

Comment: I'm still confused with this. can u point me to the changes should I do in employes.html in order to avoid this error.

Comment: now I understand those are predefined variables of thymeleaf. thank you @metroids

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have any problem in DB or spring-data-jpa.
Thymeleaf is causing it. I seem you havn't added any indexemploye object in model which you want to use in thymeleaf.
You can add object in model like:

```java
    @GetMapping("/showPost/{id}")
    public String showPost(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
        Post post = postService.getPostById(id);
        postService.generateTagsString(post);
        model.addAttribute("post", post); // Now object Post can accessed in thyemeaf with name post
        return "show_post";
    }
```

Comment: no I didn't add the indexemploye object in model. can you show me how please.

Comment: ```java
@GetMapping("/showPost/{id}")
    public String showPost(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
        Post post = postService.getPostById(id);
        postService.generateTagsString(post);
        model.addAttribute("post", post);
        return "show_post";
    }
```

Comment: i just added the codebase url: if u wanna take a look at it

Comment: i did that in EmployeController.java & ServiceController.java

Comment: I don't see where is the problem here !!

Comment: I saw your code and error log `"currentPage==status.indexemploye"` this causing error.
I am not sure why.

Comment: Compiler is not happy with EL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230447/discussion-between-ismailalabou-and-krishnkant-jaiswal).